# Get Yesterday's Data Dynamically in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table that store loan records and I need to compare today's data with yesterday's. The problem is, my company didn't process and store any data on Sunday or public holiday, so every Monday or the day after public holiday data always be NULL.

My table looks like this

```
LOAN_DATE  | YSTR_DATE | ACC_NO  | BALANCE       | LOAN_ID
2022-01-07 | null      | 5000093X| -619294125.98 |  LO1
2022-01-07 | null      | 1079653X| -650000000.00 |  LO2
2022-01-08 | 2022-01-07| 5000093X| -619294125.98 |  LO1
2022-01-08 | 2022-01-07| 1079653X| -650000000.00 |  LO2
2022-01-10 | null      | 5000093X| -619294125.98 |  LO1
2022-01-10 | null      | 1079653X| -650000000.00 |  LO2
2022-01-11 | 2022-01-10| 5000093X| -619294125.98 |  LO1
2022-01-11 | 2022-01-10| 1079653X| -650000000.00 |  LO2
2022-01-12 | 2022-01-11| 5000093X| -596544416.08 |  LO1
2022-01-12 | 2022-01-11| 1079653X| -650000000.00 |  LO2
```

How can I get and join the data from Saturday or day before public holiday?

This is my dbfiddle:
https://dbfiddle.uk/9NLAopij

Comment: Did I get you right, that you provided here the result of your query and not your table contents? This table contents contradicts with one provided at the link otherwise. If yes, then it would be convenient to have the exact result desired on your sample table contents as well.

Comment: Meanwhile I'll try to guess. Is [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/LjbZ7Sfb) what you really need?

Comment: @MarkBarinstein Ah yes, I will edit my question. Thanks for noticing

Comment: @MarkBarinstein yes that exactly what I needed! Care to explain what is LAG function is?

Comment: Look at the description of this OLAP function and others at the [OLAP specification](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=expressions-olap-specification) link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as is.

```
WITH LOAN (LOAN_DATE, ACC_NO, LOAN_ID, BALANCE) AS(
VALUES
(DATE ('2022-01-07'), '5000093X', 'LO1', -619294125.98),
(DATE ('2022-01-07'), '1079653X', 'LO2', -650000000),
(DATE ('2022-01-08'), '5000093X', 'LO1', -619294125.98),
(DATE ('2022-01-08'), '1079653X', 'LO2', -650000000),
(DATE ('2022-01-10'), '5000093X', 'LO1', -619294125.98),
(DATE ('2022-01-10'), '1079653X', 'LO2', -650000000),
(DATE ('2022-01-11'), '5000093X', 'LO1', -619294125.98),
(DATE ('2022-01-11'), '1079653X', 'LO2', -650000000),
(DATE ('2022-01-12'), '5000093X', 'LO1', -596544416.08),
(DATE ('2022-01-12'), '1079653X', 'LO2', -650000000)
)
  
    SELECT
          LOAN_DATE
        , LAG (LOAN_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY ACC_NO ORDER BY LOAN_DATE) as YSTR_DATE
        , ACC_NO
        , LOAN_ID
        , BALANCE
        , LAG (BALANCE) OVER (PARTITION BY ACC_NO ORDER BY LOAN_DATE) as YSTR_BAL
    FROM
        LOAN
    ORDER BY 
        LOAN_DATE
```

| LOAN_DATE | YSTR_DATE | ACC_NO | LOAN_ID | BALANCE | YSTR_BAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-07 |  | 1079653X | LO2 | -650000000.00 |  |
| 2022-01-07 |  | 5000093X | LO1 | -619294125.98 |  |
| 2022-01-08 | 2022-01-07 | 1079653X | LO2 | -650000000.00 | -650000000.00 |
| 2022-01-08 | 2022-01-07 | 5000093X | LO1 | -619294125.98 | -619294125.98 |
| 2022-01-10 | 2022-01-08 | 1079653X | LO2 | -650000000.00 | -650000000.00 |
| 2022-01-10 | 2022-01-08 | 5000093X | LO1 | -619294125.98 | -619294125.98 |
| 2022-01-11 | 2022-01-10 | 1079653X | LO2 | -650000000.00 | -650000000.00 |
| 2022-01-11 | 2022-01-10 | 5000093X | LO1 | -619294125.98 | -619294125.98 |
| 2022-01-12 | 2022-01-11 | 1079653X | LO2 | -650000000.00 | -650000000.00 |
| 2022-01-12 | 2022-01-11 | 5000093X | LO1 | -596544416.08 | -619294125.98 |